# Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.IFileProvider' while attempting to activate my controller

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1, fileprovider-extension

I have this in my controller

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders;

[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]

public class PlanningController: ControllerBase
{
 private readonly IFileProvider fileProvider;

 public PlanningController(IFileProvider fileProvider)
 {
  this.fileProvider = fileProvider;
 }

[HttpGet]
[Route("GetTest")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetTest()
{
  return NotFound();
}
```

When I call to getTest I get this error

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.IFileProvider' while attempting to activate 'api.Controllers.PlanningController'.
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, bool isDefaultParameterRequired)

Stack Query Cookies Headers Routing
InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.IFileProvider' while attempting to activate 'api.Controllers.PlanningController'.
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, bool isDefaultParameterRequired)
lambda_method(Closure , IServiceProvider , object[] )
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActivatorProvider+<>c__DisplayClass4_0.b__0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider+<>c__DisplayClass5_0.g__CreateController|0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

I'm using ASP.NET Core 3.1

Any idea, please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Solved

I have added this in Startup.cs to inject in my controller

```
IFileProvider physicalProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
services.AddSingleton<IFileProvider>(physicalProvider);
```

Thanks